# How to select with ease several circular areas in a square array?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently defining an area that way :

```
target=zeros((256,256))
```

If I want to define for instance 2 squares areas out of this big zone, i can do that :

```
target[50:60,50:60] = 1
target[100:110,100:110] = 1
```

If I want to define a circular area of parameter 5 for radius around the center, I can do that :

```
target[where(hypot(indice1,indice2)<5)] = 1
```

But how can I easily define several circular areas which would not be around the center, but a specific location ?

In other words, how to define a circular area of radius 8 centered on position (10,10), another one of radius 2 centered on position (123,35) ...

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(256),np.arange(256))

mask = ((xx-10)**2+(yy-10)**2 < 8**2) | ((xx-123)**2+(yy-35)**2 < 2**2)

target[mask] = 1
```

Comment: Well, it seems to work perfectly well ! Thank you. I had the feeling I was going to need meshgrid, but at that time I did not find out how to use it.